# log JSON queries built through ElasticSearch High Level Java Client for debugging?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, elasticsearch-query, resthighlevelclient

I use ElasticSearch High-Level Client Java API in my Spring Boot application. I want to log the queries built using High-Level client API for debugging purposes.

My question is what kind of settings required in my application.properties file to turn on JSON queries built from my application?

I tried out the following properties to the application.properties file. However, it does not print the JSON queries built using various query builders.

```
logging.level.org.elasticsearch.client=TRACE
logging.level.org.elasticsearch.client.sniffer=TRACE
logging.level.org.elasticsearch=TRACE
```

Comment: Thank you Opster Elastisearch Ninja for providing the solution.

Comment: those log configuration setting  are quite good because I was able to get the HTTP request

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply log the queries built using the rest-high level client, using the below code in your logger.

**You can also have control of which types of queries you want to log and what types of levels (TRACE, INFO, DEBUG) you want to set in specific cases.**

### Code to get and log the search JSON

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("employee").source(sourceBuilder);
log.info("Search JSON query: {}", searchRequest.source().toString());
```

The first line, is used to create a search request and second line is used to print the `search JSON`, Note `searchRequest.source().toString())` which is used to get the search JSON string.

Let me know if you face any issue, I do this all the time using the rest-high-level client.

Comment: Thank you @Opster Elasticsearch Ninja. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

[elasticsearch logging doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/7.17/java-rest-low-usage-logging.html) seems too ambiguous, but it mentions `tracer`:

> Enable trace logging for the tracer package to have such log lines printed out.

If you dive into the es client code, there is a class called `org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.RequestLogger`, which logs all the requests and responses detail into a logger named `tracer`:

```
private static final Log tracer = LogFactory.getLog("tracer");
```

In method `logResponse`, you can see that it logs debug info into normal package logger, trace info into `tracer` logger.

**So the right way to show request & response trace info is to configure a logger named `tracer`, and enable `TRACE` level for it.**

Using `logback.xml` for example:

```xml
    <appender name="ES_REQ_RES_TRACER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/es-trace</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/es-trace.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
            <maxFileSize>500MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="tracer" additivity="false" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="ES_REQ_RES_TRACER" />
    </logger>
```

Now you can find trace details in `logs/es-trace` file. It will contains a curl request and a json response.

`TRACE` level for `tracer` logger can also be configured in `application.properties` if you use spring boot:

```
logging.level.tracer=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch has guides on how to do client logging.

> To see what is actually sent to and received from the server Request / Response logging on the transport level needs to be turned on as outlined in the snippet below.

Enable transport layer logging

```
<logger name="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE" level="trace"/>
```

The above applies to both the RestHighLevelClient and ReactiveElasticsearchClient when obtained via RestClients respectively ReactiveRestClients.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.logging