# ElasticSearch NEST multi match returns all result

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have this C# code which is expected to match 2 fields using `multi-match` Elastic Search type. I am using NEST package.

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<FileDocument>(
     s => s.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(c => c
     .Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.FileName).Field(query))
     .Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.Metadata).Field(query))
     )));
```

Problem is no matter what text I passed in, it returns all the result. Anything I miss out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved after adding `.Query(query)`

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<FileDocument>(
                 s => s.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(c => c
                 .Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.FileName).Field(p=>p.Metadata))
                 .Query(query)
                 ))
                 );
```

Reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-match-usage.html

Comment: you can mark it answer, after sometime so that it would be helpful for community, also any pointer how you debugged and found that its missing :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to efficiently debug these types of issue, you need to inspect the HTTP request going to Elasticsearch, ultimately your query builder will be converted to **search JSON** and will be executed against Elasticsearch.

I am not aware of `nest` but have written the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852022/4039431) for Java code, which prints the Elasticsearch query in JSON format.

Although my guess is that, you are not sending the correct HTTP method which should be `POST` and you might be sending it with `GET`, which is causing ES to ignore your search query and return all documents.

Comment: Thanks. I realize I miss out the `.Query(query)`