# opensearch SearchRequest query logging

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am using "opensearch-java:2.8.1".
In the Elasticsearch java client, I was able to logging my query in the following way.

```
    SearchRequest searchRequest = searchRequestBuilder.build();
    log.info("query: {}", searchRequest.toString());
```

However, in the opensearch java client, the implementation of toString is different.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Is there any way I can log a query?

Comment: `searchRequestBuilder` is an object of which class? `SearchRequest` comes from opensearch-java?

Comment: @Kartoos SearchRequest : org.opensearch.client.opensearch.core.SearchRequest
searchRequestBuilder : co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest

opensearch-java and elasticsearch-java have the same structure. only toString is different..

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` method you are referring to, comes from `Object.java` itself which is parent of all the classes in java. Since, `SearchRequest` is actually not overriding it, hence the the [implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) is being taken from `Object.java`.

The implementation difference between `toString()` comes from the fact that it is implemented in [elasticsearch-java](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/a5ecc5e7b1b90fb6172ffdbe2803535de2915e16/java-client/src/main/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/RequestBase.java#L72) but not implemented in [opensearch-java](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-java/blob/5edb45a218dd777ff055abaf55f3668913ef085a/java-client/src/main/java/org/opensearch/client/opensearch/_types/RequestBase.java).

Now coming to the issue of logging information from SearchRequest, you will need to use some other methods which can give you your desired info. For example I see

```java
searchRequest.q() # Query in the Lucene query string syntax
```

Or as per this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852022/7801965), if you want to print query:

```java
searchRequest.source().toString()
```